# make a custom error message and prevent duplicate mail id from inserting in db

Tags: codeigniter-3

I have checked email unique in codeigniter. In else past I diplayed error. But the system error is not convenient. how to customise error...

i have tried giveng javascript alert instead of that error message... but after that alert the data are storing in database.. Actually the data should not store in database if the email is not unique..

public function add_applicants() {

```
    //     $field_name=$this->input->post('photo');
    $data = $this->input->post();
    $mobile = $this->db->get_where('applicants',array('mobile_number'=>$this->input->post('mobile_number')));
        if($mobile->num_rows()>0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Mobile Number Already Registered");                
        }   
        $email = $this->db->get_where('applicants',array('email_id'=>$this->input->post('email_id')));
        if($email->num_rows()>0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Email_id Already Registered");                
        }   
     $school_id= $this->input->post('school_code');
      $name_of_exam= $this->input->post('name_of_exam');
        $name= $this->input->post('name_candiadte');
      switch($name_of_exam){
        case '1':
        $exam='NMMS';
        break;
           case '2':
        $exam='NTS';
        break;

      }
      $school_code = $this->Welcome_Model->getschoolData($school_id);

     if (isset($_FILES['photo']) == 1) {
        $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . 'uploads/'.  $school_code->name_of_the_school.'/'. $exam ;
        $this->upload_path = $config['upload_path'];

        if ($this->validate_upload_path() == TRUE) {
            $config['upload_path'] = $this->upload_path;
            //               print_r($this->upload_path) ;
            // die();
        }
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg';
        $config['max_size'] = 2000;
        $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
        $config['overwrite'] = true;
        $config['file_name'] =  $name.'-'.date('Ymdhis') . '.jpg';
        $file_name = $config['file_name'];
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('photo')) {
            $this->upload->display_errors();
        }
    }

            $data['photo'] = $file_name;

    $insetapplicants = $this->Welcome_Model->insertApplicants($data);
    if ($insetapplicants == 'Success') {
        echo "<script>

         alert('New Applicants Added Successfully');
         // window.location.href='dashboard';
         </script>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you are throwing exceptions when you can handle this a whole lot simpler...Just generate an appropriate error message and display it.

Comment: How are you checking that your post values exist and are in the correct format etc. Have you read up on form validation?

Comment: no I have done inline jquery validation in view itself

Comment: You should also do server side validation. What you can do then, when your submit event is triggered, is to perform an AJAX call to check the email address and then create any error messages you desire. That would be part of your jquery form validation.

Comment: You have to check if the email address already exists. Make a function to do it.

Comment: $email = $this->db->get_where('applicants',array('email_id'=>$this->input->post('email_id')));
        if($email->num_rows()>0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Email_id Already Registered");                
        }    i have done tyhat in that function itself